# extract image path using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I request information form web service using ajax and this service return image for me and I need to use the image in my code.

my issue with this service, it is return difference of text:

- Form 1: "/site/images/test.png"
- Form 2: "/site/images/test.png?size=3"
- Form 3: "`<img src='/site/images/test.png />`"
- Form 4: "`<img src='/site/images/test.png?size=3' />`"
- Form 4: "`<div><img src='/site/images/test.png?size=3' /></div>`"
- Form 5: "" return empty string

this service bring data from legacy system and based on the users input that time, I cant change the service. I need way to extract the image path using JavaScript. this path should be the image path only without any tags or query strings.

Note: the Images extension will be any type

Comment: Just to be clear, you need the fullpath or just the filename ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex, will match all the images:

```
/(\/.*?\.\w{3})/img
```

[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tK5hQ3/5)

---

Your code may look like this:

```
var image = "<div><img src='/site/images/test.png?size=3' /></div>";
result = image.match(/(\/.*?\.\w{3})/img);
console.log(result[0]);
```

---

Output:

```
/site/images/test.png
```

---

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/jPNzEV)

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex you should use:

```
.*?(\/[\/\w\.]+)[\s\?]?.*
```

See it in action on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cN9eZ2/1).

[image]

How to use it in Javascript:

```
var rex = /.*?(\/[\/\w\.]+)[\s\?]?.*/;
var res = rex.exec("<img src='/site/images/test.png?size=3' />");
console.log(res[1]);  //Will print /site/images/test.png
```

Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sxdkfvc/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
(\/.*\.\w+)
```

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aI8aW2/1)

[image]

**Javascript** code

```
var re = /(\/.*\.\w+)/g; 
var str = 'Form 1: "/site/images/test.png"\nForm 2: "/site/images/test.png?size=3"\nForm 3: "<img src=\'/site/images/test.png />"\nForm 4: "<img src=\'/site/images/test.png?size=3\' />"\nForm 4: "<div><img src=\'/site/images/test.png?size=3\' /></div>"\nForm 5: "" return empty string';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```